# Status of NodeMCU for ESP32

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esp32

I was looking at the docs for the dev-esp32 branch, no docs for net? But I see in the sources there's a code file that defines it?  How likely is it my 8266 code will run on the latest ESP32 firmware?

Do interrupt pins configured with gpio.wake, wake it up from a dsleep?  Can multiple wake-up pins be set?

I guess the question is, is this firmware still a million miles away from being substantially useful, or is it worth ordering a chip and kicking its tires now?  (That no esp32 tag yet exists on SO seems like a bad sign.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least [wifi](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1615) module has been refactored in `dev-esp32` branch, so it's definitely not 100% portable. Also, ticket [#1612](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1612) mentions both addition of gpio.wakeup() for configuring wake-from-sleep-on-GPIO-level functionality, and that they're not attempting to be "NodeMCU for ESP8266" API compatible. Note that this is accurate at the time of writing, and everything is subject to change in the future.

Comment: I ordered one from elektrodragon, couldn't resist -- wish they had the dual core option on a dev board, but given the async nature of NodeMCU probably not that important.  Thanks.